# How to add risk constraint in PortfolioAnalytics?

Tags: r

I am trying to add a risk constraint to my portfolio optimization, i.e. std < xy.

I checked the manual on how to add constraints on page 11,
[http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/PortfolioAnalytics.pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/vignettes/custom_moments_objectives.pdf)
but couldn't find any information about how to add a risk **constraint** (not objectives).

I also looked at the manual on how to use custom functions,
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/vignettes/custom_moments_objectives.pdf
but it looks like they apply **only for objectives**, **not for constraints**.

So my question is how do I specify risk constraints to optimize portfolios like

```
max return with std < x
```

etc.

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: see example 3, http://www.rinfinance.com/agenda/2015/workshop/RossBennett.pdf

Comment: but again, these are objectives, not constraints (if I am not mistaken)?

Comment: I guess the example was not clear enough. At the moment I am only looking to specify one risk constraint (I edited the question accordingly). was this the issue you refered two as dual problem, i.e. the two constraints specified previously? anyway, in example 3 you mention I only see the risk target (in this case expected shortfall) specified as objective but i'd like to specify it as constraint.

Comment: You are trying to do some kind of linear maximization with convex constraints, maybe other packages handle that kind of problems: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=maximization+with+convex+constraints+in+r-project